# How send voice to wit.ai from Telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, wit.ai

I'm trying to use wit.ai to understand intent and entities in a voice command received from user in a Telegram bot.

```
def discover(bot, update, user_data):

   voice = bot.getFile(update.message.voice.file_id)
   voice.download('file.ogg')

   client = Wit(wit_access_token)

   with open('file.ogg', 'rb') as f:
       resp = client.speech(f, True, {'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg'})
   print('Yay, got Wit.ai response: ' + str(resp))
```

But, I'm receiving this error from Wit client:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:/Users/PAGANEFR/PycharmProjects/MARCoBot/readaudio.py", line 8, in <module>
resp = client.speech(f, True, {'Content-Type': 'audio/ogg'})
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wit\wit.py", line 88, in speech
data=audio_file, headers=headers)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wit\wit.py", line 41, in req
' (' + rsp.reason + ')')
wit.wit.WitError: Wit responded with status: 400 (Bad Request)
```

I can play ogg file with VLC. File seems consistent.
I have tried to convert ogg file to wav with soundfile library:

```
data, samplerate = sf.read('file.ogg')
sf.write('file.wav', data, samplerate)
```

But I'm receiving this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1599, in <module>
globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1026, in run
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
File "C:/Users/PAGANEFR/PycharmProjects/MARCoBot/readaudio.py", line 6, in <module>
data = sf.read('file.ogg')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 257, in read
subtype, endian, format, closefd) as f:
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 624, in __init__
self._file = self._open(file, mode_int, closefd)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1179, in _open
"Error opening {0!r}: ".format(self.name))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\soundfile.py", line 1352, in _error_check
raise RuntimeError(prefix + _ffi.string(err_str).decode('utf-8', 'replace'))
RuntimeError: Error opening 'file.ogg': File contains data in an unimplemented format.
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What did you searched so far?

Comment: I would like a function where I pass audio file and it returns the text (speech to text) where is specified the action (intent) and attributes (entities). Example: audio="I want order a pizza with onion and tuna"; action is "order" and attributes are pizza, tuna and onion.

Answer (score 0):

I have read this on [sungjin han' blog](https://blog.meinside.pe.kr/Implement-a-Speech-to-Text-Bot-Using-Wit-Ai-API/) but it's golang maybe helpful, You could see this part, He has used [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/) convertor, but it's on golang language...
His [github](https://gist.github.com/meinside/56f2616c61f59768b4ce487bea4f9fd5).

```
func speechToText(w *witai.Client, fileUrl string) (text string, err error) {
    var oggFilepath, mp3Filepath string
    // download .ogg,
    if oggFilepath, err = downloadFile(fileUrl); err == nil {
        // .ogg => .mp3,
        if mp3Filepath, err = oggToMp3(oggFilepath); err == nil {
            // .mp3 => text
            if result, err := w.QuerySpeechMp3(mp3Filepath, nil, "", "", 1); err == nil {
                log.Printf("> analyzed speech result: %+v\n", result)
                if result.Text != nil {
                    text = fmt.Sprintf("\"%s\"", *result.Text)
                    /*
                        // traverse for more info
                        sessionId := "01234567890abcdef"
                        if results, err := w.ConverseAll(sessionId, *result.Text, nil); err == nil {
                            for i, r := range results {
                                log.Printf("> converse[%d] result: %v\n", i, r)
                            }
                        } else {
                            log.Printf("failed to converse: %s\n", err)
                        }
                    */
                }
            }
            // delete converted file
            if err = os.Remove(mp3Filepath); err != nil {
                log.Printf("*** failed to delete converted file: %s\n", mp3Filepath)
            }
        } else {
            log.Printf("*** failed to convert .ogg to .mp3: %s\n", err)
        }
        // delete downloaded file
        if err = os.Remove(oggFilepath); err != nil {
            log.Printf("*** failed to delete downloaded file: %s\n", oggFilepath)
        }
    }
    return text, err
}
```